# UART on STM32F091 stops receiving data even if they're sent

Tags: stm32, uart, rs485, stm32f0

So, I'm having strange behavior regarding the serial number of my board with an STM32F091.

I have a Python software that sends a packet on the serial port every 100 ms. I have initialized the serial port on the ucontroller with the same settings as are set in the Python software to transmit.

```
/* USART2 init function */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 38400;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
  
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, &cdr2, 1);
}
```

I'm using the RX callback to manage the RX on the serial port

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *UartHandle)
{
  /* Set transmission flag: trasfer complete*/
  if (UartHandle->Instance == USART2)
  { 
    rx2[puwrrx2] = cdr2;
    
    if( puwrrx2 < ( RX2_LEN - 1 ) )      
      puwrrx2++;                   
    else
      puwrrx2 = 0;
    
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, &cdr2, 1);
  }
}
```

and the TX callback to put back the serial in RX

```
void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *UartHandle)
{
  /* Set transmission flag: trasfer complete*/
  if (UartHandle->Instance == USART2)
    DE_RS485_LOW;
}
```

with

```
#define DE_RS485_HIGH             HAL_GPIO_WritePin(RS485_En2_uC_GPIO_Port, RS485_En2_uC_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET)
#define DE_RS485_LOW              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(RS485_En2_uC_GPIO_Port, RS485_En2_uC_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET)
```

I trasmit every 100 ms with a function that calls

```
DE_RS485_HIGH;
HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, tx2, packet_lenght);
```

For some reason, I still have to understand why, at a certain point, the serial stops receiving data or, at least, the rx2[] buffer stays empty even if I'm sending data.

Is there a way to check if the UART goes in error and, at least, reset it to make it work again?

***UPDATE***

After some investigation, I found out that the main issue is that `RxXferCount` goes to zero for some reason. This put the `RxState` to `HUAL_UART_STATE_READY` instead of putting the state back to BUSY RX.

The CR1 register has also the bit 2 RE: Receiver enable set to 0 and the ISR register shows both `FE: Framing error` and `NF: START bit Noise detection flag`.

The main issue is that when everything I've just described happens, the `HAL_UART_ErrorCallback` is not called

Staying in debug I've noticed that the only callback my code enters in is the `USART3_8_IRQhandler`

From what I understand is that with `RxXferCount=0` the micro do not automatically clear the errors and goes back to the RX mode, but stays stuck in the situation I've just described

Comment: On the similar STM32G series there is certainly a UART error bit in the status register which you will need to clear down if it gets set. I'm sorry I'm not familiar with the API I wrote my own drivers. Check the data-sheet for a thorough description of the registers, the STMCube API is not a good way to learn how the device works. If you are getting errors on a regular basis you may have a signal integrity issue.

Comment: One such flag is overrun flag (new data byte arrived while previously received byte wasn't read from the data register DR/RDR). If it's not cleared, it locks up the UART.  `UART2->ISR` register contains all flags. Please, explain what exactly your funny variable names mean, where and how they're declared, what their types and/or lengths are.

Comment: Also the UART should be able to trigger the transmit enable (driver enable in the datasheet) pin for you, rather than you bit-bashing the GPIO. You need to enable that feature in the UART and configure the GPIO routing appropriately. Presumably the board designer has connected the transmit enable on the board to a GPIO that can be configured for this purpose.

Comment: @Ilya that seems to do the job. Do you have a link on where I can find the documentation for that register? On the datasheet of the MCU and the programmer guide I can't find anything

Comment: In general, for almost everything you need, you need 4 documents: Datasheet (electrical/mechanical properties), Reference Manual (description of MCU peripherals from the manufacturer - including UART, timers, clock configuration, with all their registers), Programming Manual (description of core peripherals by ARM, with their properties and registers, such as memory protection unit or an interrupt controller) and Errata Sheet (in case there is a silicon bug - always a good idea to quickly glance through the list of bugs to be aware of them). You're looking for a reference manual here.

Comment: You say "TX callback to put back the serial in RX" but I don't see any code that transmits anything, nor anything that "calls" DE_RS485_HIGH`.

Comment: @pmacfarlane you're right. added the code but it's a simple routine that is fired every 100 ms

Comment: So, I've found more info about the issue, checking also STM32F0 library and HAUL functions